# querying rally with curl

Tags: rest, curl, rally

In a perl script, I am sending my curl request to rally such that it looks like this:

```
$url= "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/Defect?query=\(FormattedID%20%3D%20DE36578\)";

$cmd = "curl -s -k \"$url\" -o ${return} -b ${rallycookies}";
system($cmd);
```

I expect to see human readable English text in the return file.  What I see is:

> > ^*\213^H^Cí\224ANÃ0^PE÷=Å(ûtÚ
> >     ¤R\o ^HØ´
> >     ½\200ãL±%'^Nö¤%·ÇIz^AØÒYØ^Z\217ß\237¿úÂpíäL^XRUºjb^E\206¹Íé«³çmöä^[¦\206ócßR^Fzê¶^YÓ7ã\200>\2026*DâíÛÇ>*¯ï^*òe\206I\211-
> >     ;\222»^P|\200»Å^R^:ç@ul^Roµbë^[°^QÂ°'P^EìAiM1^B\233ñ=ú.h^R8     Í^D^-\226¾ê¥0+ùz<^^`W^TûbX\220æ«4må!øÒQ}U³Í'`t5^¨\214^TÎ
> >     V^S\236Wó^E>Ó\2114Ï¡ ^U}³Id     ©þlt^PHgò^V¥°RÄZ9'^OþB^CXöðNÌý^FQà4^R\230~\225^AÇÅ¿©Ù\215ºQ7ê?S)^QÇ(^\222qÌð^*{²q^DË^E

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like the return is compressed. Try adding `--compressed` and see if that gives it back to you in English.

Comment: That provided me with the information I needed!  It is having an authentication problem, so was encoding it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that authentication was failing.  Rather than putting in a human readable message, it showed junk.

Once I added the --compressed that Larry suggested, it showed me a human readable message, I was able to correct the problem and the original command I posted worked.